# Binding render callback in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

According to [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) documentation:

> Whenever a UI action causes an attribute of a model to change, the
>   model triggers a "change" event; all the Views that display the
>   model's data are notified of the event, causing them to re-render.

So I suppose that render() method should be bound to "change" event by default. However the following code does not work:

```
TestModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
TestView  = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
        alert('render called');
    }
});
var mod  = new TestModel;
var view = new TestView({model:mod});
mod.change();
```

It works only if I add explicit bind call:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
}
```

Does this mean that my understanding of default render() callback is not correct and we should always bind render() callback by hand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless something has changed in the last few months, yes, that is the case. This is a good thing, as it gives flexibility as to when views are rendered/re-rendered (for example, some applications might want to render a view only after a model has been persisted on the server, not necessarily when it changes in the browser). If you want your views to always re-render when a model attribute changes, you can extend the default backbone view with your own base view that binds its render method to the model change event, then extend all your concrete views from that. Ex:

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        Backbone.View.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        this.model.bind('change', this.render);
    }
});

MyConcreteView = MyView.extend({...});
var model = new Backbone.Model({...});
var view = new MyConcreteView({model: model});
model.set({prop: 'value'});
```

Comment: Note that you dont win that much, cause when ever you need do to more in you initialize method you have to call `MyView.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);`

Comment: Takin a view in the backbone source, it seems a better idea to override `Backbone.View._configure()` instead of `Backbone.View.initialize`. Cause you can use initialize as before and dont need to call the super method when ever you wanna use it in your concrete view implantation.

Comment: I agree, invoking the 'parent' version of the same method is verbose, but I would be wary of overriding methods that are not explicitly documented, they're technically internal and have a higher likelyhood to change. When they do change, you would have to update your implementation to match it. If you really do not like the verbose way of invoking the parent method, a better solution might be to add your own initialization method that has a different name, and call it from MyView.initialize.

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine the Backbone.View constructor to set the render callback by default after creating a new view using the code beneath:

```
Backbone.View = (function(View) {
  // Define the new constructor
  Backbone.View = function(options) {
    // Call the original constructor
    View.apply(this, arguments);
    // Add the render callback
    if (this.model != null) {
      this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
    } else {
      // Add some warning or throw exception about 
      // the render callback not being triggered
    }
  };
  // Clone static properties
  _.extend(Backbone.View, View);
  // Clone prototype
  Backbone.View.prototype = (function(Prototype) {
    Prototype.prototype = View.prototype;
    return new Prototype;
  })(function() {});
  // Update constructor in prototype
  Backbone.View.prototype.constructor = Backbone.View;
  return Backbone.View;
})(Backbone.View);
```

Now you can create a new view like so:

```
view = new Backbone.View({model: new Backbone.Model})
```