# When does jquery associates function with element?

Tags: jquery, html, backbone.js

My HTML code is generated at rumtime using backbone.js and templates.

My template looks like below

```
    <script type="text/template" id="my_template">
        <% _.each( results, function( item, i ){ %>
        <div id="myelement<%=i%>"  class="myelement">

            <div id="name<%=i%>" class="elementname" >
                <%= item.get("category").name %>
            </div>

            <div class="clickclass" >
                I want to click here
            </div>
        </div>                    
        <% }); %>
    </script>
```

And I have written a jquery function to trap click on class "clickclass"

```
       $(".clickclass").click(function() {
            alert("her");
            var outerdiv = $(this).parent('.myelement');
            alert(outerdiv.attr("id"));
        });
```

If i use the generated html page code and see in jsfiddle, it works fine.

I think its about when does jquery associates function. As when jquery code loads, there is nothing on HTML page.

Am i correct or there is something else?

Comment: That is correct. The element must exist on the page before `$(".clickclass").click(` is executed.

Comment: You might be trying to attach the click before the template is loaded into the DOM.

Comment: I agree Kevin. Was reconfirming. So whats the way out? How do I re-atttach once view has been rendered?

Comment: There are several questions/answers about this on SO already and probably even more from other sources if you google it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [calling javascript on rendering views in BackBone js. post-render callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145680/calling-javascript-on-rendering-views-in-backbone-js-post-render-callback)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126642/backbone-js-getting-callback-of-render-within-the-view

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731915/binding-render-callback-in-backbone-js

Comment: Why aren't you using the `events` in a view for this? Generally you want to localize event handling to the view that created the element.

Comment: Here is What I did, Please let me know if correct approach. I have moved the click function after render call has returned. Hence I will always have elements. I cant use the methods given in above threads as  they distort the view. (some functions get called even before view has been rendered. )

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation:

```
$('body').on('click', '.clickclass', function() {...});
```